# Load single field from pymongo as an array

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I have a list of mongo objects that I basically want to pluck a single field from.

So let's say my objects are structured like this

```
[
    {'name': 'Lucy', age: '24'},
    {'name': 'Nicole', age: '22'},
    {'name': 'John', age: '28'},
]
```

I want to load an array from PyMongo in the format `['Lucy', 'Nicole', 'Lauren']`.

One way to do this is just a simple python list comprehension:

```
names = [p['name'] for p in db.people.find({'age': {'$gt': 18}}, ['name'])]
```

That works fine, but if there are a lot of records it's very slow. Is there a more efficient way of doing this?

Comment: Do you want to include duplicates? i.e. if there are two docs with the same `name` should that name show up twice in the output?

Comment: Either way is acceptable, the data I'm working with would not actually have duplicates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as you don't need to include duplicates, you can do this by calling [`distinct`](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/cursor.html#pymongo.cursor.Cursor.distinct) on the cursor returned by your `find` query:

```
names = db.people.find({'age': {'$gt': 18}}).distinct('name')
```

Comment: I'm impressed! This ran about 5x faster than the list comprehension.